# MySQL delete from database where

Tags: mysql, sql

Within my database, I have a large number of tables which contain dates. These are expiry dates to be precise.

Currently, I perform the following commands to remove any rows which are older than a specified date using:

```
 DELETE FROM tablename WHERE DATE(datepoint) < '2019-03-18'
```

1) Is there a way I can instead search and delete from an entire database instead of manually changing the table name and running the command each time?

Comment: If by "database" you mean all the tables in a database, then the answer is maybe, but you would have to use dynamic SQL for that.

Comment: *"Is there a way I can instead search and delete from an entire database instead of manually changing the tablename and running the command each time?"* No let me geuss you have alot off table names which keep the data but with numbers as table name.

Comment: *"but you would have to use dynamic SQL for that."* @TimBiegeleisen dynamic SQL also will not help.. `PREPARE`/`EXECUTE` clauses in MySQL can also one execute one MySQL statement at a time.

Comment: @RaymondNijland ... or write a script in some external tool such as Bash or Java.

Comment: indeed @TimBiegeleisen that is a option, or PHP because `mysqli` is tagged

Answer (score 1):

You could use a PHP function, Anyway I wouldn't recommend deleting any records, just filter your queries for the last 3 months only

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider having expiry dates in their own table EXPIRY_DATES. It sounds like it could be an important concept in your domain. Then have your other tables point to the correct expiry date using a foreign key. Using on delete cascade rules from EXPIRY_DATES would clean out records from all child tables when you delete one expiry date from EXPIRY_DATES.

Answer (score 0):

you shoould use procedure (or function):

Define a procedure :

```
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE delete_from_table(OUT table_name char(20))
-> BEGIN
->   delete from table_name WHERE DATE(datepoint) < '2019-03-18';
-> END//
mysql> delimiter ;
```

CALL procedure :

```
mysql> CALL delete_from_table(@table1);
mysql> CALL delete_from_table(@table2);
mysql> CALL delete_from_table(@table3);
```